# Python: faster implementation for loop

Tags: python, performance, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to run following code with variable limit in this case being in the range of milions:

```
limit = 6000000
for i in range(limit):
           s[i] = some_function(i)
```

With some_function being a relative simple function without for loops in it (ex.: 2**i).

How can I make this run faster? (maybe by using numpy?)

Comment: I think more information of what ectually this function do can address if you can use numpy vecrotization...

Comment: If the goal is to run `some_function` 6 million times there is no faster way.

Comment: @mkrieger1 #parallelize #vectorize

Comment: Can you please accept any answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets try make some speed improvment for your example...

```
import nupmy as np 
limit = 6000000
s= np.arange(limit) 
s = s**2 
print(s[:10])
```

This using numpy vectorize should make big deal when it comes to python loops speed, it is under the using the Cython module that convert parts of the code to c (or c++ I dont remember...)

Answer (score 1):

If the loop is large and you have other unused processor, please check [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) library as this is python's hacky way to allow parallelization of processes.

The first example in the link is all you need:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
n_pools = 5 # You will need to  play with this number. Increase or decrease and check performance.
with Pool(n_pools ) as p:
    print(p.map(some_function, range(limit)))
```

Answer (score 1):

If `some_function` is just `2**i` then `numpy` could speed thing up for you. You'd just call `numpy.power`:

```py
import numpy as np
elements = np.power(2, range(10000))
```

As suggested by Benoit Descamps before me, you could speed things up even further when using multiprocessing.

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
  return x**2

p = Pool(5)
p.map(f, range(10000))
```

#### Comparison

multiprocessing VS numpy VS map VS for-loop

```
$ echo -e "from multiprocessing import Pool\ndef f(x):\n  return x**2\np = Pool(5)\np.map(f, range(10000))" | python -m timeit -n 1000
1000 loops, best of 5: 4.83 nsec per loop

$ python -m timeit -n 1000 'import numpy as np; np.power(2, range(10000))'
1000 loops, best of 5: 1.09 msec per loop

$ python -m timeit -n 1000 'list(map(lambda v: v**2, range(10000)))'
1000 loops, best of 5: 2.07 msec per loop

$ python -m timeit -n 1000 'import numpy as np; [np.power(2, i) for i in range(10000)]'
1000 loops, best of 5: 8.92 msec per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution of using map() is very fast as compared to for loop

```
limit = 6000000
def some_function(i):
    return i**2
s=list(map(some_function,range(limit)))
```

Comment: Numpy is still twice as fast but.. interesting that using `map` speeds things up that much as well